# Does JasperReports have distinctcount(col1,col2) option?

Tags: crystal-reports, jasper-reports

We have crystal report already built  with us. We need to understand and make crystal to *JasperReports*. We are using *iReport 4.5.1* for designing reports.

I want to know that crystal provides distinctcount(col1,col2) fields , what is the similar option available for the *JasperReports*?

Please let me know if am not clear with my question

Comment: I don't this is a crystal question as you need data about Jasper...

Comment: When I have taken group band and I dragged any field to that group and it will ask for ditinct,count,etc...I want to display data with distinct(count(col1,col2)) in jasper reports. is it possible to do that?

Comment: I am sorry to say I have expertise in only using crystal not jasper... you may need to try in jasper community only